# How to load SQLite3 database with log file entries using perl

Tags: database, perl, module, sqlite, dbi

I have an assignment In my Perl class that contains two programs, the first is to create a database and table using the DBI::SQLite  for Perl, i have already completed the first part of the program, but i have no idea how to go about doing the second part. The second part involves getting the source IP and destination port pairs from a log file and inserting them into the table using the SQL insert statement. The table created in the first program contains two columns, one for  source IP and one for Destination PORTS, the program shouldn't produce any output except a count of the rows added to the table. as you can see below the code that i have put represents how the table was setup, i would really appreciate some help on learning how to fill the table. The log file needed for the second program is available @ this link: http://fleming0.flemingc.on.ca/~chbaker/COMP234-Perl/sample.log

The code for my first program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(          
    "dbi:SQLite:dbname=test.db", 
    "",
    "",
    { RaiseError => 1}
) or die $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->do(<<'END_SQL');
CREATE TABLE probes (
    source CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    port CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (source, port) )
END_SQL
```

Code for the second program (not working out)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my %ip2port;
my $IPCount = keys %ip2port;
my $portCount = 0;
my $filename = "./sample.log";
open my $LOG, "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
LINE: while (my $line = <$LOG>) {
my ($src_id) = $line =~ m!SRC=([.\d]+)!gis; my ($dst_port) = $line =~ m!DPT=([.\d]+)!gis;
my $dbh = DBI->connect(          
    "dbi:SQLite:dbname=test.db", 
    "",                          
    "",                          
    { RaiseError => 1 },         
) or die $DBI::errstr;


$dbh->do("INSERT INTO probes VALUES($src_id, $dst_port )");
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO probes VALUES(2,'$dst_port',57127)");
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT SQLITE_VERSION()");
$sth->execute();

my $ver = $sth->fetch();

print @$ver;
print "\n";

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
}
```

Comment: break the problem into 2 parts: 1) extracting the ip and port, and 2) inserting them into the db.

Comment: i have tried the code i am putting under the first program

Answer (score 0):

Read the files line by line (dozens of examples in the net).

```
my ($src_id) = $line =~ m!SRC=([\.\d]+)!gis;
my ($dst_port) = $line =~ m!DPT=([\.\d]+)!gis;
```

Then insert this data to the database. (Dozens of examples in the net).

Some reading: http://www.perl.com/pub/1999/10/DBI.html

Comment: can you take a look at the second program i put up